# Can a script running off selenium grid interact with the files on the node VM?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I am testing a website that should be sending a piece of information to an installed program.

I would like to use Selenium grid to have the script running off multiple VMs, and use Selenium to automate the tasks in the website, then use regular Java to open the log file of the program installed on the Node VM and check for reciept of information.

My question is am I able to interact with the files on node VMs using selenium grid or am I only able to interact with the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clear on the architecture of Selenium grid. The hubs are like servers which tell the clients running on the nodes to perform actions on the browser using the chrome/firefox driver. So your hub should not be able to execute anything on node as i understand.

Having said that you can use this [**code**](http://selenium.polteq.com/en/get-remote-ip-address-of-node-selenium-grid/) **to find out the ip of the node** in which the current session is running and then remotely execute in that machine whatever you want using tools like [**PsExec**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) , which should solve your problem.